# TYPO3 Extbase - Failing to render json via typnum

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-7.6.x

TYPO3 Extbase - Failing to render json via typnum

Next to list/edit/new/remove action (which work) I tried to render the output in json. But no values render. If I do a simple ...

```
$data = array('value'=>'001');
return json_encode($data);
```

It does return ...

```
{"value":"001"}
```

What am I missing?

**Edit:** With using and referencing to the same repository its working:

JSONController.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Lei\Controller;
use Vendor\Lei\Domain\Model\Lei;

/**
 * JSONController
 */
 class JSONController extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\ActionController {

/**
 * leiRepository
 *
 * @var \Vendor\Lei\Domain\Repository\LeiRepository
 * @inject
 */
protected $leiRepository;

/**
 * @var string
 */
protected $defaultViewObjectName = 'TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\View\JsonView';

/**
 * action jsonRequest
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function jsonRequestAction() {

    //$data = array('value'=>'001');
    //return json_encode($data);

    $this->view->setVariablesToRender(array('records'));
    $this->view->assign('records', $this->leiRepository->jsonRequest());

}           

}
```

LeiRepository.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Lei\Domain\Repository;
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\QueryInterface;

class LeiRepository extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Repository {

...

public function jsonRequest() {

    $query = $this->createQuery();
    $result = $query->setLimit(100)->execute();
    return $result;

}

}
```

Comment: Does your `jsonReturn()` method return anything? And I think `setVariablesToRender()` does not expect an array, but I am not sure right now. I wrote an article about the JSON view here: https://usetypo3.com/json-view.html

Comment: I was looking at it :-) How can I check if jsonReturn() returns anything? I tried to dump ( var_dump($result); ) it in the JsonRepository.php and was looking at the typnum ... but nothing there. I more or less followed the tutorial of the Simple Blog Example and my List/Edit/New controller looks like it (with limit and search) https://github.com/maddy2101/simpleblog/blob/master/Classes/Controller/BlogController.php . All working. Regarding the setVariablesToRender() I just followed other examples like https://www.snip2code.com/Snippet/282519/TYPO3--Extbase--Simple-JsonView-usage .

Comment: I played around a little more and get the following error: Could not find class definition for name "Vendor\Lei\Domain\Model\Json". This could be caused by a mis-spelling of the class name in the class definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you inject and use a `JsonRepository` extbase expexts a domain object called `Json`. If you just want to render already existing domain objects as their JSON representation, just use the same repositories you used in your `listAction()` and `detailAction()`.

Have a look at my example: https://usetypo3.com/json-view.html

Also, a debug after the `return` like you did in your repository will never be executed.

Comment: Ahh ... thanks for the hint. With using the same repository now it's working! I updated above! Thanks a lot!