# TYPO3 Extbase - Manipulate/Change returning json

Tags: json, typo3, extbase, typo3-7.6.x

How can I manipulate/change the returning json from:

```
[{
    "name": "Audi",
    "owner": "Peter",
    "price": 0,
    "color": "Blue",
    "pid": 0,
    "uid": 1
}, {
    "name": "BMW",
    "owner": "Wolfgang",
    "price": 0,
    "color": "Black",
    "pid": 0,
    "uid": 2
}]
```

to e.g.:

```
{
"data": [{
        "DT_RowId": "row_1",
        "name": "Audi",
        "owner": "Peter"
    }, {
        "DT_RowId": "row_2",
        "name": "BMW",
        "owner": "Wolfgang"
    }],
    "options": [],
    "files": [],
    "draw": 1,
    "recordsTotal": "2",
    "recordsFiltered": "16"
}
```

I tried this in my controller, but it's not even filtering for name & owner:

```
/**
 * @var string
 */
protected $defaultViewObjectName = 'TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\View\JsonView';

public function jsonRequestAction() {           
    $this->view->setVariablesToRender(array('records'));                        
    $this->view->setConfiguration(array(
            'records' => array(
                'only' => array('name', 'owner')
            )   
        )
    );      
    $this->view->assign('records', $this->leiRepository->jsonRequest());                    
}
```

I still get all the fields in the standard json.

That's the function from the repository:

```
public function jsonRequest() {

    $query = $this->createQuery();
    $result = $query->setLimit(1000)->execute();
    //$result = $query->execute();
    return $result;

}
```

Comment: Can you post the code from `$this->leiRepository->jsonRequest()`?

Comment: The function from the repository for jsonRequest() ? I provided above ...

Comment: And how do you get JSON? Don't see any `json_encode()` or similar.

Comment: It's coming from the JsonView. I updated above. Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42471172/typo3-extbase-failing-to-render-json-via-typnum or http://blog.pluswerk.ag/2014/04/02/typo3-cms-6-2-lts-was-ist-neu-in-extbase-fluid/ Happy to do it with json_encode too though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your own JsonView in Controller:

```
/**
 * JsonController
 */
class JsonController extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\ActionController {

    /**
     * view
     * 
     * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\View\JsonView
     */
    protected $view;

    /**
     * defaultViewObjectName
     * 
     * @var string
     */
    protected $defaultViewObjectName = \Vendor\Extension\View\JsonView::class;

    /**
     * action list
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function listAction() {

        $response = [
            'draw' => $draw,
            'start' => $start,
            'length' => $length,
            'recordsTotal' => $allProducts->count(),
            'recordsFiltered' => $allProducts->count(),
            'order' => $order,
            'search' => $search,
            'columns' => $columns,
            'data' => $filteredProducts
        ];
        $this->view->setVariablesToRender(['response']);
        $this->view->assign('response', $response);
    }

}
```

Be aware to biuld the entire $repsonse in controller as like as the DataTables expects it (last lines above). And here is the JsonView:

```
/**
 * JsonView
 */
class JsonView extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\View\JsonView {

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $configuration = [
        'response' => [
            //'_only' => ['draw', 'start', 'length', 'order', 'columns', 'recordsTotal', 'recordsFiltered', 'data'],  
            'data' => [
                '_descend' => [
                    'product' => [
                        '_only' => ['uid'],
                    ],
                    'orderType' => [
                        '_only' => ['uid'],
                    ],
                ],
                '_descendAll' => [
                    //'_exclude' => ['title'],                      
                    '_descend' => [
                        'maturity' => [],
                        'currency' => [
                            '_only' => ['title'],
                        ],
                        'updated' => [],
                        'customer' => [
                            '_only' => ['title', 'title_short', 'titleShort'],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],                 
            ],
        ],        
    ];    

    /**
     * Always transforming ObjectStorages to Arrays for the JSON view
     *
     * @param mixed $value
     * @param array $configuration
     * @return array
     */
    protected function transformValue($value, array $configuration) {
        if ($value instanceof \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage) {
            $value = $value->toArray();
        }
        return parent::transformValue($value, $configuration);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `JsonView` configuration is only capable of filtering/reducing data - this cannot be used to add additional computed properties like like requested in the initial question. Besides that, the keyword is `_only` instead of `only`.

You don't need to to use `json_encode()` and still can use `JsonView`. However the data payload has to be computed in your controller individually - thus, to contain e.g. `recordsTotal` and `DT_RowId` properties.